# 3D Bar Chart - City Visualization

Tags: 3d

Is there any Javascript/flash library to draw 3D Bar Charts like this one?

http://ehp.niehs.nih.gov/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/ehp.1206244.g002.png

I need to be able to draw different width/depth/height bars depending on some values.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could create this chart using [Orson Charts for HTML5](http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/web/index.html).

Disclosure: I am the author of this 3D chart library.